# Form submit button does not work in Firefox but works in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with some input fields and a submit button. The form should submit to a  servlet.

When I hit submit/return, everything is fine in Chrome or IE, but it does nothing on Firefox. Any idea about the issue?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <form>

        <table cellpadding ='2' border ='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="Database">Database</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="database" type="text" onchange="setdirtybit()" name="Database" style="width:200px"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="Script">Script</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="script" type="text" onchange="setdirtybit()" name="Script" style="width:200px"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
            <input type ='submit' value='Submit' onclick='Close()'></input>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Close()
    {
        window.returnValue = "";
        if(window.dirtyFlag)
        {
            document.forms[0].method="post";
        document.forms[0].action="/nbreports/updates/";
        document.forms[0].submit();
            window.returnValue =    getValue('database') + '/' +
                        getValue('script') ;
        }
        window.close();
    }

    function getValue(varName)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(varName) == null)
            return "";
        if(document.getElementById(varName).value == null)
            return "";
        else
            return document.getElementById(varName).value;
    }

    function setdirtybit()
    {
        window.dirtyFlag = 1;
    }
```

Comment: what does the `Close()` method do? Consider posting its code, distilled to what is relevant to this issue.

Comment: Combining SUBMIT and ONCLICK is not straightforward. You need to handle the event properly.

Comment: This page is displayed as a popup. The Close() method is intended to return the values to the parent page. The code has been added

Comment: i usually use button type and put all my serialization/submit/after actions in the function

Comment: @FlavorScape : I added manual submission code in the Close function and removed the same from form tag. Now it works like a charm in firefox, but in chrome it's not.

Comment: Please post the submission code you added to close() and see if any console errors exist. It's probably something simple preventing execution in Chrome.

Comment: is the close() method getting called (can you log that?) And looks like  <input type ='button' onclick='Close()'></input> basically need to debug where exactly it's failing in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mytextfield').change(function(e) {
    $('input[type=submit]').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put an Id on your submit button, them do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitButtonId').click(function(){
        var url = 'myServletUrlHere';
        var data = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: alert("It worked!")
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Snuffleupagus So? he didn't say I couldn't use it. I gave him an answer to his problem using jQuery. So why turn down my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I do know that the following form does not work in Firefox but it works in all the other browsers:

```
<form method="POST">
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" name="body"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It's like the submit button doesn't even process the mouse clicks.